# How to parse JSON in Swift?

Tags: json, swift

I have some JSON data that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLWOA.png) which I am trying to parse in Swift.

```
[
  [
    {
        a: "1",
        b: "2"
    },
    [
        {
            c: "3",
        },
        {
            d: "4",
        }
    ]
 ]
```

]

```
        let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments)

        if let myArray = json[0] as? [[AnyObject]] {
            for myObject in myArray {
                print("This works!\(myObject)")
            }
        }
```

However nothing I try seems to work - any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use SwiftyJSON - https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

or create a class based on your JSON scheme try to parse with it.

like:

```
class object
{
  let data = Array<subObject>()
}
class subObject
{
  let subData = Array<Dictionary<AnyObject,AnyObject>>()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This snippet is not JSON. If it was JSON, the keys would be strings, like this:

```
[
  [
    {
        "a": "1",
        "b": "2"
    },
    [
        {
            "c": "3",
        },
        {
            "d": "4",
        }
    ]
 ]
]
```

And anyway **in your screenshot we see that your JSON has already been parsed**!

What you show in the image is not JSON either, but an array containing arrays and dictionaries...

---

But let's say your JSON is actually valid and the missing quotes are just a copy/paste problem.

**Then to achieve your goal you have to cast the result of NSJSONSerialization to the correct JSON format, *then* you can access the inner objects.**

Like this, for example:

```
do {
    if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? [[AnyObject]] {
        if let myArray = json.first {
            for myObject in myArray {
                print("This works!\(myObject)")
            }
        }
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```